# bit.ly URL Reduction service suddenly not working

Tags: coldfusion, bit.ly, cfhttp

I am using cold fusion code to covert URL to bitly urls and just last week it stopped working. I have tried everything but it just will not work.

The original code below was working:

```
<cfhttp result="CFHTTP" method="GET" url="https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="access_token" value="#bitly_access_token#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="longUrl" value="#URL.long_url#">
</cfhttp>
```

But now it is not and the cfhttp.filecontent is just returning "Connection Failure"

however when I put the same URL in a browser:

https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=ac46e2c56bd20dcaefe3f55be5ca&longUrl=http://www.url.com

it works. Any idea why this would be happening? Does anyone know if bit.ly changed anything?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://dev.bitly.com/index.html, there's a big notice stating

> API V3 will be deactivated on March 1, 2020. If you are currently using V3, migrate to V4 as soon as possible to avoid a breakdown of your integrations.
>   See all the changes in our updated documentation for API V4.

You've got 2.5 weeks to move to v4.

Comment: Adrian, I did see that and we were planning to address the changes. However this is occurring now before the switch over. Does anyone see anything blatant that would be causing this not to work? The exact link vars work in a browser but not in the cfhttp code. Thanks!

Comment: If your code hasn't changed and you're getting "Connection Failure", then it's either a network issue on your end or something's changed on their end. It's possible they're testing their EOL process and you're getting affected. Have you contacted their support yet?